# How to find <span> Element within <tr> by XPath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

My HTML Code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody id=a>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <span>
                                   some Text
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <span>
                                   some Text2
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <span>
                                   some Text3
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
              </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to select each of the span elements by their text. I'm able to select the tbody by id. I Tried this:

```
tbody.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format(".//span[contains(text(), {0}))]", &var)));  
(var = somex0020Text)
```

but this always returns the first `<span>` element in my table.

I also tried:

```
tbody.FindElements(By.XPath(String.Format(".//span[contains(text(), {0}))]", &var)));
```

which returned a list containing every single `<span>` element in my table, and I don't know why.

I also don't understand why

```
tbody.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format(".//span[text() =  {0})]", &var)));
```

throws an Element not found Exception, when the contain method returns a `<span>` element with just the same text.

Answer (score 2):

I tried by using xpath as:

```
.//span[contains(text(),'some Text')]
```

it is selecting all the 3 span.

so to this i have refer to parent element.

for 1st span: `.//tbody[@id='a']//tr[1]//span[contains(text(),'some Text')]`

for 2nd: `.//tbody[@id='a']//tr[2]//span[contains(text(),'some Text')]`

for 3rd: `.//tbody[@id='a']//tr[3]//span[contains(text(),'some Text')]`

through this I can select every span element individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery to get all the span elements within "Table".

Example:

```
    var items = $('table div span');
    items.each(function (x) {
        alert(items[x].innerHTML);
    });
```

Comment: Short and sweet explanation.

Comment: Except jQuery cannot be combined with WebDriver.

Comment: You meant to say the solution above is not appropriate... if so,  what's wrong in the above solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Venkat, it introduces dependencies. The page is required to have jQuery, and therefore if jQuery doesn't load the test will break (regardless of if the application breaks), and it inherently bypasses native Selenium methods (i.e you are working *against* the API).

Answer (score 0):

> tbody.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format(".//span[contains(text(), {0}))]", &var)));
>   (var = somex0020Text)
>
> but this always returns the first Element in my table.

This is an expected behavior in Selenium. As i can see, there are 3 elements with the same xpath as mentioned in your code, in this case **Selenium returns the first element**.

> tbody.FindElements(By.XPath(String.Format(".//span[contains(text(), {0}))]", &var)));
>
> which returned a list containing every single Element in my table, and i dont know why.

This is also an [expected behavior in Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). `FindElements` will return all the elements with the same xpath.

So change the value of `var` to `some Text2` or `some Text3` to locate the other two elements.

The following `xpath` will work for `some Text2` :

```
.//span[contains(text(), 'some Text2'))]
```

Comment: i would expect selenium to return the only one Element matching the XPath and the text? I understand the XPath is the same for all 3 Elements but the text is unique.

Comment: I should've said not one of the texts contains any other text.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Xpath $x("//tr//span[contains(.,'some Text')]")

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see, you are having a trouble with the `contains`. All 3 spans are containing this 'some Text' portion.

If you want to check the entire string, you could use `.//span[text()='some Text']`.

Hope this helps, and have fun with web parsing!